# access exception for yarn user on /user/yarn for oozie job

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie, sqoop

I am running a oozie workflow in which sqoop command is included. The sqoop command runs fine when submitted through terminal. But the oozie workflow gives following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=yarn, access=WRITE, inode="/user/yarn":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
```

Please suggest what might be wrong.

Sqoop command in workflow:

```
<command>
  import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://server_name\inst1:1434;database=DB_NAME" --username ***  --password-file ***** --table qw_product  --hive-import --hive-table db_ccms.qw_product
</command>
```

Comment: did you provide all required permission to yarn path during cluster configuration ..??

Comment: Not sure on that. Which permission should be given to yarn path exactly ?

Comment: chmod 755 /path/to/yarn

Answer (score 1):

add a property

to tell yarn not run container as yarn but the workflow user

HADOOP_USER_NAME=${wf:user()}

refer this link

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/26593/permission-denied-useryarn-accesswrite-oozie-shell.html